# query with $or duplicate value when I reverse the conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two very close queries who should return the same result but they don't.
One is returning the good documents and the other is returning the same good documents with duplicates.

My wish is to never have these duplicates

```
db.getCollection('MyCol').count({
"$or":[
        {c1},
        {c2}
    ],    
})
```

return 225 results

```
db.getCollection('MyCol').count({
"$or":[
        {c2},
        {c1}
    ],    
})
```

return 226 results

I am using mongo 2.4

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

`count` returns an estimate of the count. By definition it isn't guaranteed to return the accurate count. If you need an accurate count, use `countDocuments` driver helper.

Comment: is there an equivalent find the "find" request ?

Comment: You can construct your own aggregation pipeline using $count stage to filter etc.